# Online portfolio or Offline portfolios?

Tags: ux-designer, guidelines, portfolio, jobs, recruitment

I am a working individual who wants to switch over to UX design.

I am trying to create a portfolio for my first project, but I am conflicted: I am not sure whether my portfolio should be a web page or offline (such as a PDF). Based on my searches, I can only find information about having web pages for portfolios. Is it better to have both options when applying for jobs, or is either/or sufficient? If I prefer to create it offline, will this potentially be an issue or give recruiters a negative impact?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You create a portfolio only to be able to show your work to others. It is however a matter of how discrete you need to be who you give access. Sending it to one person (in a PDF) or having a website that is accessible for anyone, it's up to you to decide.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, I think you should have both versions, online and offline. But offline version a bit higher priority, since you can quickly send it via a link. Not everyone are ready to open a strange file.